# Selenium Webdriver: Element is not currently visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I used the same type of code to select the drop down there the code is working fine but in this case i tried to click on the button. am getting the error as Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 31 milliseconds

```
JavascriptExecutor executor3 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor3.executeScript("document.getElementById('iskpiFilterAction').style.display='block';");
driver.findElement(By.id("iskpiFilterAction")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
```

The Problem is the type is hidden and the html tags as follows:

```
<input id="iskpiFilterAction" type="hidden" value="1" name="isKpiFilterAction">
```

Can any one please check the code and give me solution or sample code.

Comment: what in the world is `".style.type='hidden'"`? Hidden inputs are not visible on the page, how would you click them????

Comment: Is there any way to click the button if it is hidden please suggest me a solution

Comment: Please anyone give me some example for the above html tag

Comment: It is not a button. input type hidden is NOT a BUTTON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As epascarello mentioned in the comment, `#iskpiFilterAction` is *not* a button, it's a hidden `<input>` element. Therefore, you can't `click()` it here:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("iskpiFilterAction")).click(); // this won't work
```

Comment: Yes, i aggree with your comment. Then i target the ID of button with your above code now it is working fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Also, what people usually do with a element like that, which is either visible or not is use `ExpectedCondition.visibilityOfElement()` like so:

```
WebElement foo2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
      .visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("iskpiFilterAction")));
```

Whereas, the regular way of getting a element might be:

```
WebElement foo2 = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
      .presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("iskpiFilterAction")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Selenuim Actions class to simulate user interactions which will make the button visible to the user--

for example:

WebElement menu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("));

```
    Actions build = new Actions(driver);
    build.moveToElement(menu).build().perform();//Hovers the mouse over the first element which will trigger the event
    WebElement m2m= driver.findElement(By.xpath(""));// finds the previouslly hidden element
    m2m.click();
```